# How to specify no account for Windows Service installer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

For a Windows Service project, the ServiceProcessInstaller has a property named "Account".  VS.NET forces a value for this. It's auto generated code in the installer's CS file.

I want to specify the account value through installutil parameters.

How do I not specify a value for "Account" in VS.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply keep the ServiceProcessInstaller.Account default value (serviceAccount = ServiceAccount.User, with empty username and password). The private GetLoginInfo() method of ServiceProcessInstaller then will look for values from the Context.Parameters dictionary (e.g. "username", "password") that can be passed on the installutil command line.

To further customize the values it should also be possible to override setting in the BeforeInstall event of the servive as shown here: http://dotnetstep.blogspot.de/2009/06/passing-parameter-to-installutil.html

See also the msdn article for the [ServiceProcessInstaller.Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.account.aspx) Property.

Comment: After setting it to User, I no longer see where Account is being assigned anything in the auto generated code.  Username and password are both assigned nulls.